# What is the best way to stream stdout from a Process, in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-io

I would like to run a Process, and stream the process's stdout to the console. What is the best (most effective, easiest to understand, least lines of code) way to do this?

For example:

```
var process = await Process.start(exec, args);
```

I'd like to see any stdout contents as soon as they are available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

```
import 'dart:io';
void main() async {
   var process = await Process.start(exec, args);
   process.stdout.pipe(stdout);
}
```

Or using `then`:

```
import 'dart:io';
void main() {
   Process.start(exec, args).then(
      (process) => process.stdout.pipe(stdout)
   );
}
```

https://api.dart.dev/dart-async/Stream/pipe.html

Comment: I wonder what the pros and cons are between this and addStream are?

Comment: `.pipe()` itself just calls `addStream()` ;-), but in addition, when the source stream is closed without an error, it also closes the target stream automatically.

Comment: Wouldn't this do some unexpected things if it closed your process's stdout stream before your process is done?

Comment: You can't close it, because the controller is private to the process. What you can do is stop listening and that won't have any effect except not getting further output on the stream.

Comment: Thanks, dude :) it's help me for async processes

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way:

```
var process = await Process.start(exec, args);
stdout.addStream(process.stdout);
```

Notice that I add the `process.stdout` stream to the normal `stdout` stream, which comes from `dart:io`.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, you could use the `mode` argument in `Process.start` and pass a [ProcessStartMode.inheritStdio](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.3.1/dart-io/ProcessStartMode/inheritStdio-constant.html)

```
var process = await Process.start(
  command,
  args,
  mode: ProcessStartMode.inheritStdio
);
```

Be careful though, this will, as the mode's name implies, pass on all stdio from the process (stdin, stdout and stderr) to the default stdout which might cause unexpected results as stuff like sigterms are passed on too.